# How to scrape tweets with english language only in twint?

Tags: python, twint

I have tried the following syntax:

```
c>lang = 'en'
```

But it still fetches non-english tweets as well.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to answer the question. Please read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include lang:en in the Search object.

```
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = " lang:en vegetables"
twint.run.Search(c)
```